# Renew of 3 years working visa as married in Germany

Tags: visa, germany, marriage

How much time before my visa (3 years visa as married with a German National) expires? Can I apply for a new one?

Answer (score 2):

First of all: you have a residence permit (visa is only issued by counslates and then only for a short of about 3-6 months).

On your question: check out the information of your responsible immigration office.

Often they give advice as to when to hand in application for extensions.
In Berlin, a new application can only be applied for **8 weeks before** the current permit expires.
An appointment, well in advance, should therefore be made between the 7th and 8th week.

Comment: Thank you David. It was very uselful